# List of all people who liked a comment.

Tags: like

I have a 168 likes on a comment and want to view all the people who have liked it. How can you view this?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really clear on how you want to get at this information. It can be found by going into Central Administration, Application Management, Manage Service Applications, and going to the User Profile Service. Within there, there will be a link called Manage Social Tags and Notes.

Here you can provide a URL or a user and see what tags or notes have been left on the page or by the user.

There are web service end points to get to this information as well as server side code (obviously).

Expand your question so you get the response you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I cannot check the details, as I don't have a 2013 environment (you are on 2013, right?). Also: are you in a Microblog or where is your comment?

However if you have the information LikesCount you also have a hidden column LikedBy.That column contains a csv list of the users who liked your comment.
Depending on "who you are", e.g. developer, admin, etc. there are different ways to see the values. Also it's unclear if you only want to check for this one comment or always display who liked a comment in the UI.

To be able to see that on this specific comment you'd still need to find the comment in the respective MicroFeed list.